# How to show the recent apps in the Overview button?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, launcher

On Android KitKat v4.4.2 that came with my phone the Overview button (the button that is not Home nor Back) is showing the home screen settings:

How can I change the button behavior to show the list of recent applications instead?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My old android 4.4 phone had me press and hold the home button, while that third button would pull up a menu. I believe that was how things worked in Android 4.4 days.